# Create exclusion constraint with non commutative operator in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a question about exclusion constraint.

I have a following table:

```
-- auto-generated definition
create table archives_seasonmodel
(
    id                   serial    not null
        constraint archives_seasonmodel_pkey
            primary key,
    series_id            integer   not null
        constraint archives_seasonmodel_series_id_e05c6f84_fk_archives_
            references archives_tvseriesmodel
            deferrable initially deferred,
    last_watched_episode smallint
        constraint archives_seasonmodel_last_watched_episode_check
            check (last_watched_episode >= 0),
    season_number        smallint  not null
        constraint archives_seasonmodel_season_number_check
            check (season_number >= 0)
        constraint season_number_gte_1_check
            check (season_number >= 1),
    _order               integer   not null,
    number_of_episodes   smallint  not null
        constraint archives_seasonmodel_number_of_episodes_check
            check (number_of_episodes >= 0),
    episodes             hstore,
    translation_years    daterange not null,
    constraint archives_seasonmodel_series_id_season_number_4368dab7_uniq
        unique (series_id, season_number),
    constraint last_watched_episode_and_number_of_episodes_are_gte_one
        check (((last_watched_episode >= 1) OR (last_watched_episode IS NULL)) AND (number_of_episodes >= 1)),
    constraint mutual_watched_episode_and_number_of_episodes_check
        check (number_of_episodes >= last_watched_episode)
);

alter table archives_seasonmodel
    owner to postgres;

create index archives_seasonmodel_series_id_e05c6f84
    on archives_seasonmodel (series_id);

create index archives_seasonmodel_series_id_season_number_4368dab7_idx
    on archives_seasonmodel (series_id, season_number);

create index exclude_overlapping_seasons_translation_time_check
    on archives_seasonmodel (translation_years, series_id);
```

In general this table contains 3 specific columns:

`series_id`  -  positive integer, foreign key to table  archives_tvseriesmodel

`season_number`  – positive integer,  number of season in  series

`translation_years`  - daterange, translation dates range of each season in series

General idea:

Series contains multiple seasons.

Each season has `season_number` (from 1 to infinity) that represents obviously number of seasons in series.

Each season has `translation_years`  daterange which represent start and end date of  each season.

There are exclusion constraint ‘`exclude_overlapping_seasons_translation_time_check` thats prevents
`translation_years` dateranges from overlapping each other.

But there are another problem in validation. I need to maintain `translation_years` in a such way that season with number for example 4 has datarange fully lower then season 5.

For example:

```
correct:

season_number =4 , translation_years =(2012-01-01, 2013-01-01)

season_number =5 , translation_years =(2013-03-01, 2014-01-01)

incorrect:

 season_number =4 , translation_years =(2012-01-01, 2013-01-01)

season_number =5 , translation_years =(2010-01-01, 2011-01-01)
```

what I tried to do:

```
ALTER TABLE archives_seasonmodel
ADD CONSTRAINT test
EXCLUDE USING gist(series_id WITH =, translation_years WITH <<)
WHERE (season_number = season_number - 1 )
```

But it says that only commutative operator  are allowed in constrains, and << is not a commutative one.

Question is is it possible to make a such constraint somehow?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps instead of strictly left operator (<<) try with the range overlap operator (&&). See [Range Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html). **NOT TESTED** as I do not have a DB available at the moment.

```
alter table archives_seasonmodel
  add constraint test
      exclude using gist(series_id with =, translation_years with &&)
      where (season_number = season_number - 1 );
```